# O Android Studio diz que algumas classes não foram usadas e quase todo código está vermelho

Tags: android-studio

Eu estava a mexer um pouco no código, quando de repente ele ficou desse jeito que vocês podem ver na imagem abaixo.
Não faço ideia do tenha causado isso, tentei fazer o **Clean** e o **Rebuild** e nada.

A maioria dessas classes que ele aponta como não usadas, estão a ser usadas e onde estão usadas, ele fica vermelho dando o `Cannot find Symbol`.
Destacar que ainda sim ele compila e executa o código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido!
Sendo que as dependências já estavam lá no Gradle, eu tinha que removê-las e introduzi-las novamente e fazer o **Sync Project**.
E assim, foi corrigido com sucesso!!!